# Android: dialog box without shadow around it

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How do I remove this "shadowBox" effect around the dialog box that fades the background?

I know I can create like totally custom view but let's say I want to keep it simple. I have xml layout for dialog with only textView and 2 buttons and I want to stop the fade only for this one dialog.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try:

```
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. LayoutParams must be from android.view.WindowManager

Comment: Such constant is deprecated for targetSdkVersion=22

Answer (score 9):

create `style.xml` inside `values` and put things like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="progress_dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">#00ffffff</item> 
</style>
```

And in the end, put this style to your dialog box.

Comment: Hm, applied it as style="@style/styled_dialog" to linearLayout of my dialog.xml and nothing.

Comment: Which DialoBox are you using? a Progress one? or an Alert Dialog? I used it while having a ProgressDialog and specified the style while instantiating it.

Comment: @Sheikh-Aman I'm using Alert dialog and I can't find the way how to add style to it.

Answer (score 6):

Simply use

```
 dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: That makes the background of the dialog transparent too.  I don't think that's what was wanted.

Answer (score 2):

here give the sample class

```
public void showDialog () {

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    window.requestFeature(window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.sample);
    ImageView imggameover, imgplayagain;
    imggameover = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.gameover);
    imgplayagain = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.playagain);
    imgplayagain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), random.class));
            onStop();
            finish();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Dialog's layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gameoverlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gameover"
        android:layout_width="225dip"
        android:layout_height="160dip"
        android:background="@drawable/gameover"
        ></ImageView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/playagain"
        android:layout_width="160dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dip"
        android:background="@drawable/playagain"
        ></ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Useful thing! But that doesn't solve the fading background. It removes the dialog window :)

Answer (score 0):

Just that you know it is also possible to change the dim amount by writing this in your theme:

```
<item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.5</item>
```